# Send a variable's content to a file through FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I would like to create a file on a FTP server from a variable's content. Is this possible without writing the data to a file locally first ?

This is what I can do:

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
file_put_contents($tmpfname, $file_contents)
ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $tmpfname, FTP_BINARY);
unlink($tmpfname);
```

But I would like to send `$file_contents` without saving it first to a file.

Comment: How can you upload something that is not a file?! You can't. `$file_contents` is the content, not the file. They are 2 different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using wrappers:

```
ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, 'data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($file_contents), FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: This a really nice and elegant solution!